# Problem with showing correlation matrix with many variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

[capture of correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNYsf.png)

## first time using python

I am Tried drawing correlation matrix with seaborn.heatmap but since I have many variables (exactly 256), it is unreadable.
How can I fix that ??
Please see the picture below for more understanding of the problem.

Comment: don't plot a correlation matrix of 256. But in case you really want to do it I suggest saving the figure (increasing its height and width) to a `.svg` file

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried this solution but got the same problem on the pic. I ended reading correlation with data_frame.corr() without using any visual aspect.

Comment: can you post your code so we can help?